# Removing file extension from an array variable

Tags: arrays, perl, variables

I'm trying to remove the .png file extension that appears in many (but not all) of the variables of my outputted array. The array variables that show the extension are doing so because they weren't generated from file names in the format of "Genus_species#.png" where "#" is a number. Rather, they were generated from an un-numbered file name in the format of "Genus_species.png". I believe this line of code is creating this issue: "$genus = $file =~ s/\d.png$//r;". How do I resolve this? Please advise.

Here's my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use English;   ## use names rather than symbols for special varables

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';

opendir my $dfh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $OS_ERROR";
my %genus_species;  ## store matching entries in a hash

for my $file (readdir $dfh)
{
    next unless $file =~ /.png$/; ## entry must have .png extension
    my $genus = $file =~ s/\d\.png$//r;
    push(@{$genus_species{$genus}}, $file); ## push to array,the @{} is to cast the single entry to a referance to an list
}

for my $genus (keys %genus_species)
{
    print "$genus = ";
    print "$_, " for sort @{$genus_species{$genus}}; # sort and loop     though entries in list referance
    print "\n";
}
```

Here's the outputted array:

```
Euonymus_fortunei = Euonymus_fortunei1.png, Euonymus_fortunei2.png, Euonymus_fortunei3.png, 
Polygonum_persicaria = Polygonum_persicaria1.png, Polygonum_persicaria2.png, 
Polygonum_cuspidatum.png = Polygonum_cuspidatum.png,
```

Notice that the variable "Polygonum_cuspidatum.png" unwantingly includes the file extension because this variable was generated from a file that lacked a number in its name. Specifically, this variable should read:

```
Polygonum_cuspidatum = Polygonum_cuspidatum.png
```

Again, please advise how to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to see the same issue if you ever have a multi-digit number in a filename.  This is all due to the choice of regular expression:

```
 s/\d\.png$//r
```

This looks for exactly one digit followed by `.png`.  If you want no digit, or any number of digits before `.png` modify your regular expression as such:

```
s/\d*\.png$//r
```

That says "zero or more digits followed by `.png` at the end of the string".

Comment: I'm getting errors using "s/\d*\.png$//r". I'm researching why.

Comment: After adding the ; at end of the expression, it works... but it's only returning 513 entries rather than the expected 585. I'm researching why.

Comment: If you ever previously had `genus_species11.png` that would have resulted in an array element of `genus_species1[]` with your previous regex.

Comment: There are no file names exceeding the number 9. It's truly strange that increasing the scope of the search would return fewer files!

Comment: Re "*That says "zero or more digits followed by .png at the end of the string".*", No it doesn't. That would be `\d*\.png\z`. What you have is "zero or more digits followed by `.png` and possibly by a LF at the end of the string."

Comment: Should I change the expression then  to:" \d*\.png\z"? I'll try it and see what happens.

Comment: I get multiple errors when using: \d*\.png\z; Not sure why.

Comment: The tr/// function is used in Perl to transliterate all occurrences found in a search list with the corresponding character in a replacement list. d  - is used to delete found but not replaced characters (tr///d).  as per your mentioned scenario , after next unless condition, add these code of lines my $genus = $file;  $genus =~ tr/[0-9].png//d;   instead of my $genus = $file =~ s/\d\.png$//r;  and check

Comment: @Jeff: Just saying you get errors isn't very helpful. We can do more to help you if you give us the actual text of the error. And, please don't add them in comments - it's better to edit your question to add further details.